# SQL/Oracle issue, I receive this error " REPORTS.WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T.BILL_CYCLE: invalid identifier at line 48" , is there anyway to fix this?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAtl.png)

above is the image of the code, my objective is to have 4 columns demonstrating the prices for a bill cycle, and 4 columns demonstrating the average of all bill cycles one year before the initial bill cycle.

the first inner select works by itself and adds the 4 columns to the right in the picture below, the problem starts when I want to add second inner select the 4 columns for yearly average. initially I didn't have the "select * from", but I couldn't find a better way
the base of the problem is that I can't implement 2 Where clauses on the same column.

below is the snap shot of what I get from running only the first inner select.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzNGe.jpg)

I have tried union , join, cross join ... but none seem to work, one person suggested "window function" but I haven't worked with that yet.

this is the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EETJo.png)

RAW CODE TEXT IS BELOW:

VARIABLE START_DATE CHAR
EXEC :START_DATE :=''
VARIABLE END_DATE CHAR
EXEC :END_DATE=''

select * from
(SELECT

"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BILL_CYCLE",
"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" AS NET_TOTAL,
SUM(
SUM(
CASE WHEN "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BLI_TYPE" = 'Charges'
THEN "WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" END))  OVER() AS TOTAL_CHARGES,
SUM(
SUM(
CASE WHEN "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BLI_TYPE" = 'Credits'
THEN "WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" END))  OVER() AS TOTAL_CREDIT,
SUM(
SUM(
CASE WHEN "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BLI_TYPE" = 'Previous Weekly Billing Net Total'
THEN "WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" END))  OVER() AS PRV_INVOICED,
SUM(
SUM(
CASE WHEN "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BLI_TYPE" = 'Total Due / Receivable'
THEN "WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT"
ELSE 0 END))  OVER() AS Net_Due_Total
FROM "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"),

(SELECT

"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BILL_CYCLE",
"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" AS NET_TOTAL,
(SUM(
SUM(
CASE WHEN "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BLI_TYPE" = 'Total Due / Receivable' AND ( "REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BILL_CYCLE" BETWEEN '1-JAN-2022 4' AND :END_DATE)
THEN "WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" ELSE 0 END))  OVER()/COUNT(DISTINCT(BILL_CYCLE))) AS X

FROM
"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"

WHERE
("REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BILL_CYCLE"  BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE )
)
GROUP BY
"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."MTD_TOT" ,
"REPORTS"."WEK_MTD_BILL_SUM_HIST_T"."BILL_CYCLE"
;

Comment: It's difficult to read images of code. You will likely get a better response if you include the actual text (and preferably some scripts to populate some sample data). In this case, using standard joins (`full outer join ... on ...`) would also be easier to read than simply separating the two subqueries with a comma.

Comment: This error appears to be caused because you are referring to the underlying schema/tables in your `group by`. The `group by` is operating on the _result_ of the two subqueries, so you should alias the subqueries (if they really do work as you claim) and refer to that alias (not the underlying tables) in your `group by`. (Although I think this is the direct cause of that error message, I think your query has several other issues, so this probably isn't a super-helpful answer on it's own.)